# Are object properties value constants in Object.create?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-chain

Its a very curious question, I've been learning some Javascript and I got the code to work, but I would like to understand why this happens:

Why can I get the att and the def boost to work when they're created outside of the Object.create but the property hp is working as a constant?

```js
let Pokemon = {
  def: this.def,
  att: this.att,
  defBoost: function() {
    this.def = this.def + this.def
    return this.def;
  },
  attBoost: function() {
    this.att = this.att + this.att
    return this.att;
  },
  hpBoost: function() {
    this.hp = this.hp + this.hp
    return this.hp;
  }

}

let psyduck = Object.create(Pokemon, {
  name: {
    value: "Psyduck"
  },
  hp: {
    value: 500
  }
});

psyduck.def = 12;
psyduck.att = 20;

console.log(psyduck);

psyduck.attBoost();
psyduck.defBoost();
psyduck.hpBoost();

console.log(psyduck);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a property with a [descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), like in `Object.defineProperties` or `Object.create`, all of the attributes you don’t specify default to `false`. So when you have

```
hp: { value: 500}
```

it acts like

```
hp: {
    value: 500,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
}
```

`writable: false` means the property is read-only.

When creating a property by assignment, on the other hand, `enumerable` and `writable` both default to `true`.

Also, make sure to always write in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so assigning to read-only properties throws an error instead of failing silently!

Comment: Dude, I tried filling everything in the attributes from A to V, to see what was available for me in the autocomplete in VSCode (beginner, sorry for the lack of deep knowledge for terms). If I went all the way to W I would have seen the writable attribute.

Thank you very much! This solves my doubt!

Comment: @GuilhermePinheiroFerreira: Happy to help! By the way, there should be a shortcut to open the autocomplete without typing a prefix. I don’t use VSCode so I don’t know what it is, but maybe try Ctrl+Space?

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAH! That's actually perfect!!! AMAZING! Thanks!!!!!!!!